# How to escape ejs tags inside an ejs template string?

Tags: javascript, ejs

How can we escape the ejs tags itself inside a template?

In sails I would like to put the following code in the layout.ejs

```
<!--STYLES-->
<% if (typeof head_css != 'undefined') { %>
  <%= head_css %>
<% } else { %>
  <% if (typeof head_css_before != 'undefined') { %>
    <%= head_css_before %>
  <% } %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/importer.css">
  <% if (typeof head_css_after != 'undefined') { %>
    <%= head_css_after %>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
<!--STYLES END-->
```

but by default, all the things inside the `<!--STYLES-->` and `<!--STYLES END-->` are replaced by this template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%s">
```

as in the `sails-linker.js`.

So instead of the template `<link rel="stylesheet" href="%s">` I would like put something some more complex things, than when rendered the result becomes:

```
<!--STYLES-->
<% if (typeof head_css != 'undefined') { %>
  <%= head_css %>
<% } else { %>
  <% if (typeof head_css_before != 'undefined') { %>
    <%= head_css_before %>
  <% } %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/importer.css">
  <% if (typeof head_css_after != 'undefined') { %>
    <%= head_css_after %>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
<!--STYLES END-->
```

But the problem is when I try something like

```
<%= special_code_here %><link rel="stylesheet" href="%s">
```

this is automatically rendered. I need to escape the `<%` inside a ejs template.

How can we do this?

Comment: Have you tried the HTML entities for `<` and `>`, which are `&lt;` and `&gt;`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, I tried. The problem with this is was rendered as html entities in the layout.ejs file and there I should have the non-escaped `<%`. So in the browser appear the code I would like to have but as a plain text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<%%` escapes the EJS tags, and will give you `<%`

Here are the docs: 
[EJS](http://ejs.co/)

If I understand your question correctly this should help.

Comment: I already tried this and didn't work. Looks like sails (the framework I was using uses an old version of ejs in `ejs-locals`). I tried to update the ejs in the ejs-locals too but still not working. But because my question was about ejs I'll embrace this answer. I oppened a issue in ejs about this and the guy closed the issue and didn't help me to solve the problem at all.